# Where m2 file is stored when installing apache maven on a unix box

Tags: maven, unix

I downloaded maven gz file, unzipped same, but i dont know where the m2 is stored. I imagine im missing a step but i cant see what one?

Is there aninstall script etc?

```
[root@atddpvm5 apache-maven-3.5.4]# cd /var/tmp/apache-maven-3.5.4/
[root@atddpvm5 apache-maven-3.5.4]# ls
apache-maven     DEPENDENCIES   doap_Maven.rdf  LICENSE         maven-builder- 
support  maven-core      maven-model          maven-plugin-api           
maven-resolver-provider  maven-settings-builder  NOTICE   README.md
CONTRIBUTING.md  deploySite.sh  Jenkinsfile     maven-artifact  maven-compat           
maven-embedder  maven-model-builder  maven-repository-metadata  maven- 
settings           maven-slf4j-provider    pom.xml  src
```

Comment: As dunni already mentioned it looks like you have downloaded the source dist and not the binary distribution...

Answer (score 4):

By default the .m2 folder is stored in the home folder of the user. In this case since you are using root, the path is most likely `/root/.m2`. You also have to use the `-a` switch with `ls` to see that folder, since it's a hidden folder (it starts with a .). Note that the folder will only be created on the first usage of Maven, i.e. when you call a maven command on a maven project, like `mvn clean install`.

Additionally it looks like you have downloaded the source distribution of Maven, which only makes sense if you want to work on Maven itself. You might want to download the binary distribution, if you just want to use it.